# How can I customize my error message in yacc/lex project to display the line and type of problem?

Tags: project, bison, yacc, lex

I am new in programming but I have a yacc/lex project and some difficulty in writing the error message in detail (line and type of error). Any help with a small example, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your flex scanner definition, to cause the scanner to track line numbers:

```
%option yylineno
```

(See [the flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Options-Affecting-Scanner-Behavior.html#index-yylineno).)

Then add the following declarations to your bison grammar:

```
%define parse.error verbose
%define parse.lac full
```

(See the bison manual chapters on [error reporting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Error-Reporting) and [LAC (lookahead correction)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#LAC).

Finally, use a definition of `yyerror` which uses the line number information. At a minimum, something like:

```
void yyerror(const char* msg) {
  fprintf(stderr, "At line %d: %s\n", yylineno, msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask bad questions get correct but uninformative answers

```
void yyerror(const char *s);

extern int line_num;

void yyerror(const char *s)
{
   std::cerr << "PARSING ERROR: " << line_num << " " << s << std::endl;
   exit(1);
}
```

Comment: any version in c Language for yyerror msg

Comment: No. I suggest you read about lex and yacc instead